# Silverlight Styles - Designer Crashes

Tags: xaml, silverlight

today I wasted hours trying to fix the designer only showing "nothing" (one large white rectangle with gray borders), or showing some meaningless error (HRESULT failure blahblah).

After lots of trial&error I finally found out the reason:

The assembly which contains my styles / controls, etc. uses some system-dll's, like "System.Windows.Controls.Data" and "System.Windows.Controls.Data.Input" for types around DataGrid (which I use internally (among others) - sometimes as base-class, sometimes as "component").

When I reference my "Controls-Library" and try to use some control from there, the designer goes crazy with the errors described above. In the runtime however everything works flawless.

To get the designer working, I have to reference all assemblies, which my Library uses (directly or indirectly).

Why cannot the designer pick up those DLL-references from my "Bin/[Target]" folder? (They ARE there, even if not referenced - so the building system realises that these assemblies are needed directly or indirectly).

WPF doesn't suffer from the same problems btw.

Any "best practices" to work-around this problem?

Regards
Johannes